# No files created using fopen(); why, or where are they?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, fopen, working-directory

I am working on a CFD problem in c, using CodeBlocks (Windows). When I am trying to write the result files with fopen(), no files are created (if they are, they are nowhere to be found). The script is created as a project with several header files, and no errors occurs and the script seems to run smoothly.

I have tried running the `if (f==NULL)` but no error occurs there either.
I have also tried running CodeBlocks as admin without any luck, as well as going to Project -> Properties -> Build targets and made sure that the Execution working directory is the same as working directory. Can I have misunderstood where my working directory is?

I've tried to search the whole C: drive for the file name in case it was stored some random place but the search is negative.

Preprocessors used are stdio, stdlib and math.

I have to write several files, mostly .txt files but this is an example of a .vtf file for OpenGL graphics.

```
FILE *f = fopen("GLresults.vtf", "w+");
if (f==NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `fopen` doesn't return `NULL`, then the file must be somewhere. Have you tried searching the whole disk for it?

Comment: make sure that you have permissions to create or modify any file in the directory.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when the error indication is from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror( "my error message" );`  performs all the above correctly.  Note: after an `fopen()` error, most likely the code cannot continue, so the next statement should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: Have you tried using the full pathname? Another thing to try is to open a file for *reading* that you know exists and that you know there is permission to access.

Comment: Also, `printf("Error")` without a trailing newline may just buffer the string instead of outputting it immediately, in which case you may not see the message until much later (or not at all, if the program terminates abnormally)

Comment: please post a [mcve], including how/where you compile/link the code and where/how you execute the code.

Comment: Another thought is to insert some code before the `fopen` to check what the current working directory actually is, and print it out.

Comment: does your code call `fclose()` for each file that it opens?  It should

Answer (score 0):

Does your code is outputting Error, if not check your `<project directory>\bin\Debug\` or `<project directory>\bin\Release\` directory. For example if your project named `CFD` is in `C:\My Projects\` and Build target is selected Debug (which is selected by default) check `C:\My Projects\CFD\bin\Debug\` or `C:\My Projects\CFD\bin\Release\` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed! Tried several of the suggestions above but it turned out to be a small and hidden typo in a for-loop. Found the error by trying to read an existing file, which didnt work, so I used `return;` and `printf("hello\n")` to localize the problem.

Thanks for the help, learned a lot about debugging doing this.